# Delta live tables data quality checks -Retain failed records

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, data-ingestion, delta-live-tables

There are 3 types of quality checks in Delta live tables:

- `expect` (retain invalid records)
- `expect_or_drop` (drop invalid records)
- `expect_or_fail` (fail on invalid records)

I want to retain invalid records, but I also want to keep track of them. So, by using `expect`, can I query the invalid records, or is it just for keeping stats like "n records were invalid"?

Comment: Quarantine option described in [Delta Live Tables Cookbook](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-cookbook.html#quarantine-invalid-data) is not useful, because I want to keep the invalid records in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect` just record that you had some problems so you have some statistics about you data quality in the pipeline.  But it's not very useful in practice.

Native quarantine functionality is still not available, that's why there is the [recipe in the cookbook](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-cookbook.html#quarantine-invalid-data).  Although it's not exactly what you need, you can still build on top of it, especially if you take into account the second part of the recipe that explicitly adds a `Quarantine` column - we can combine it with `expect` to get statistics into UI:

```
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

rules = {}
quarantine_rules = {}

...
quarantine_rules = "NOT({0})".format(" AND ".join(rules.values()))

@dlt.table(
  name="partitioned_farmers_market",
  partition_cols = [ 'Quarantine' ]
)
@dlt.expect_all(rules)
def get_partitioned_farmers_market():
  return (
    dlt.read("raw_farmers_market")
      .withColumn("Quarantine", expr(quarantine_rules))
      .select("MarketName", "Website", "Location", "State",
              "Facebook", "Twitter", "Youtube", "Organic", "updateTime",
              "Quarantine")
  )
```

Another approach would be to use first part of the recipe (that uses `expect_all_or_drop`), and just union both tables (it's better to mark the valid/invalid tables with `temporary = True` marker)